# Work Done By vs Work Done On

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, work, conventions

[image]

Assuming right to be positive, in this question, is the work done **by** the boy positive or negative? I would think it is negative because the force that the boy exerts is towards the left while the movement of the boy is towards the right.

I would think that work done **ON** the boy is postive because the force that the string exerts on the boat is towards the right which is the same direction as the motion of the boy.

Am I correct? I don't quite understand how to think about the idea of work done BY the boy in this context. What does it mean for work done BY the boy to be negative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I correct? I don't quite understand how to think about the idea of
> work done BY the boy in this context. What does it mean for work done
> BY the boy to be negative?

First, some points:

1. An object does positive work on another object if the direction of the force exerted by the  object on the other object is the same as the direction of the displacement of the other object.
2. When an object does positive work on another object it transfers energy to the other object.
3. An object does negative work on another object if the direction of the force exerted by the  object on the other object is opposite to the direction of the displacement of the other object.
4. When an object does negative work on another object it acquires energy from the other object.

With respect to work done *by* the boy on the float, the boy does positive work on the float since the direction of his pulling force is the same as the direction of the displacement of the float. The boy transfers energy to (does positive work on) the float. Since the float gains energy from the boy one can say the float does negative work *on* the boy.

With respect to the anchor fixed to the pier (which, in turn,  is fixed to the Earth), the boy transfers no energy to (does no work on) the anchor fixed to the pier since there is no displacement of the fixed object (actually, there is displacement to conserve momentum, but it's imperceptible, as discussed below). Thus the boy does no work on the fixed object

Which brings us to how we treat the displacement of the boy as a result of pulling on the rope. This is where things get a little muddy (no pun intended).

The boy acquires kinetic energy when he pulls on the rope, but the energy doesn't come from the objects on the other end of the rope. It comes from the pulling effort of the boy. If the boy were 100% efficient in doing work, the kinetic energy he gains would equal the chemical potential energy he expends, for a net work (change in energy) on the boy of zero. Since he is not 100% efficient he expends more energy than he gains. But that doesn't mean he does positive work since that would necessitate transferring energy to some other object.

We can also view the movement of the boy, float, and anchor fixed to the earth, from the standpoint of conservation of momentum of the boy-object system, where the Earth is included with the fixed anchor/pier part of the system (and ignoring any friction forces or air resistance). When the boy pulls on the rope he acquires momentum equal and opposite to momentum acquired by the float, and equal and opposite to the momentum acquired by the anchor/pier-Earth system. Although the motion of these fixed objects is imperceptible due to their extremely high mass, it is not zero.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that the boy does the pulling by bending his arm and that the there are three components to consider.
A force object $B$ due to object $C$ is written as $F_{\rm B,C}$.

Object $Y$ has mass $m_{\rm Y}$, boy minus arm and object $X$ have mass $m_{\rm BX}$, and arm $A$ is massless and assume that all are initially at rest.

[image]

The arm is assumed massless to simplify matters and it is capable of exerting a constant force $F_{\rm BX,A}$ on the boy minus arm $B$ and object $X$, and of exerting a constant force $F_{\rm Y,A}$ on object $Y$.
$F_{\rm A,BX}$ and $F_{\rm A,Y}$ are the (N3L) forces exerted on the massless arm $A$.
All the force have the same magnitude $F$.

After a time $t$ the displacement of $B$ and $X$ is $x_{\rm BX}$ to the right and the displacement of $Y$ is $x_{\rm Y}$ to the left and these are in the same direction as the corresponding forces exerted by the arm so the arm does positive work on $BX$ and $Y$.
This corresponds to negative work being done on the arm which is using up its reserves of chemical energy to effect the changes.

As the centre of mass of system BXAY does not move $m_{\rm BX}x_{\rm BX}=m_{\rm Y}x_{\rm Y}$.

$Ft$ is an impulse and it changes the momentum of $BX$ and $Y$.
In terms of magnitudes $Ft=m_{\rm BX}v_{\rm BX} = m_{\rm Y}v_{\rm Y}.

The work done by the arm on $BX$ is $F\,x_{\rm BX}$ and on $Y$ $F\,x_{\rm Y}$ and these correspond to increases in the kinetic energies of $BX$ and $Y$ equal to $\frac 12 m_{\rm BX}v_{\rm BX}^2$ and $\frac 12 m_{\rm Y}v_{\rm Y}^2$.

And what is the difference between case (a) and case (b)?

In case (a) object $Y$, which includes the mass of the Earth, hardly moves at all as $m_{\rm Y}\gg m_{\rm BX}$ and so negligible work is done on it by the arm on object $Y$.
In case (b) the masses are probably of the same order of magnitude and so the arm does work on both $BX$ and $Y$.

The analysis can be continued by using the kinematic equations for constant acceleration and Newton's second law to get relationships between the impulse $Ft$ and the work done by the arm and hence the change in kinetic energy of $BX$ and $Y$.

Comment: thanks for your answer the way you broke it down made it clearer